# How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a Multiple String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

My question is so special ,

giving those Strings

```
          123456  
String1   ABCD
String2    BDD
String3     CDEF
```

As we can see

- the number of A in column 1 is 1.
- the number of B in column 2 is 2.
- the number of C in column 3 is 2.
- the number of D in column 3 is 1.
- the number of D in column 4 is 3.
- the number of E in column 5 is 1.
- the number of F in column 6 is 1.

the purpose of those calculs is to get the char that appear the most in each Column.

what is the best DataStructure i can use to handle this issue? knowing that i know the lenght of each String only at the Execution time.

the information i know already is the n° of column where each String begin.

the idea i have and i think it's not the best is iterating over the column n° and couting how much each char appear and finally finding that most occurred char.

Do you have some better solution?

**info:** My string could contain only those char[A,B,C,D,E,F]
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider the special case where each string is one character long, so you only have position 1 to consider.   Given "A", "A", "B", how would you determine that "A" is the answer?

Comment: so i create an array of  6 cases , each case for each letter , 0 for A,1 for B ....,as we have only one column i will test every first char of the String and each time i add +1 , the case where i have the max num is the case of the most occured char, in your example i will have 2 in the case 0 that means the char A , and we will have 1 for the case 2.i hope that you understood me.

Comment: I think you should write this out on paper and trace the individual steps, and keep values in variables.  This will help you understand how to express this to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "ABCD  ";
        String str2 = " BDD  ";
        String str3 = "  CDEF";
        String[] reversed = getReversed(str1, str2, str3);  // reverse rows with columns

        for(int i=0; i< reversed.length; i++){
            String trimedString = reversed[i].trim();  // removes spaces that around the string
            System.out.println(findMaxOccurrenceCharValue(trimedString));  // counts the maximum occurrence char
        }
    }

    private static String[] getReversed(String str1, String str2, String str3){
        char[] s1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] s2 = str2.toCharArray();
        char[] s3 = str3.toCharArray();

        String[] newStr = new String[6];
        for(int i =0; i<6; i++){
            newStr[i] = "" + s1[i] + s2[i] + s3[i];
        }
        return newStr;
    }

    private static String findMaxOccurrenceCharValue(String str) {
        char[] array = str.toCharArray();
        int[] count = new int[1000];
        for(char c: array){
            count[c]++;
        }

        // find the max occurrence character and number of occurrence
        String maxCharacter = "";
        int maxValue = -1;
        for(int i=0;i< array.length;i++){
            if(count[array[i]] > maxValue){
                maxValue = count[array[i]];
                maxCharacter = String.valueOf(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return  maxCharacter + "=" + maxValue;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A=1
B=2
C=2
D=3
E=1
F=1
```

Comment: Thank you , but C has to get a score of 2 not 1 , is there an error , iw ill review your solution because i'm looking for the idea behind.

Comment: Ok thanks , even if i will not agree for some stuf in your code , for example  using 1000 case for only some character is a waste of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this sample code which you can insert Strings as list so there won't be any restrictions on number of String in the code but correct output will be given. I have added inline comments where it's required.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class StringOperation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<String>();
    stringList.add("ABCD");
    stringList.add(" BDD");
    stringList.add("  CDEF");
    stringList.add("ABCD");

    char[][] array=getTwoDimentionArray(stringList);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        char[] cs = array[i];
        numberOfCharactorsinString(cs, i);

    }

}

//This method will create two dimension array from String list same time it will convert columns in to rows
public static char[][] getTwoDimentionArray(List<String> list){
    char[][] twoDimenArray=null;
    int maxLength=0;
    for (String strings : list) {
        if(maxLength<strings.length()){
            maxLength=strings.length();
        }               
    }
    twoDimenArray=new char[maxLength][list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        char[] charArray=list.get(i).toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
            twoDimenArray[j][i] = charArray[j];             
        }           
    }

    return twoDimenArray;
}

//This method will return the char occurrences in the given char array
public static void numberOfCharactorsinString(char[] charArray,int count){

    //Here we use set to identify unique chars in the char array
    Set<Character> uniqueSet=new HashSet<Character>();
    int forcount=0;
    for (Character charVar : charArray) {
        int occurent=1;

        //check whether the searching char is not empty and not a space and not in previously counted
        if( charVar!=Character.MIN_VALUE && charVar!=' ' && !uniqueSet.contains(charVar) && forcount<charArray.length){
            uniqueSet.add(charVar);
            for (int x=forcount+1;x<charArray.length;x++ ) {
                if(charArray[x]==charVar){
                    occurent++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The number of "+charVar+" in column "+(count+1)+" is "+occurent+".");
        }
        forcount++;
    }
}
}
```

If you provide input as (Note that I have added additional input in here in 4th line)

```
String1   ABCD
String2    BDD
String3     CDEF
String1   ABCD
```

The out put will be as bellow

```
The number of A in column 1 is 2.
The number of B in column 2 is 3.
The number of C in column 3 is 3.
The number of D in column 3 is 1.
The number of D in column 4 is 4.
The number of E in column 5 is 1.
The number of F in column 6 is 1.
```

Comment: thank you for your help , the solution work perfectly i gave you a vote.why i didn't choose your response ?you use a 2 for loop for finding the most occured char, so it took O(n²) , and it's not a best way to do the search.anyway , thank you , you gave me some insight.